# Angular 2 JWT doesnot sends Authorization Bearer Token during page reload

Tags: laravel, angular, jwt, angular2-jwt

I am using [Tymon JWT](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/blob/docs/docs/quick-start.md) to setup the JWT Token from my `Laravel` application.

I have setup similar to the quick start guide and when i test using the `postman`, the backend successfully returns the access token.

[image: Login Token As a response from Backend]

On frontend i am using [Angular2-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt) to send the request from frontend also replacing the `Http` module with `AuthHttp` from this package which is a wrapper for the Http module.

Configured the AuthModule similar to the guide:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { AuthHttp, AuthConfig } from 'angular2-jwt';

export function authHttpServiceFactory(http: Http, options: RequestOptions) {
  return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
        tokenName: 'token',
        noJwtError    : true, //<== Using this explicitely because i am using AuthHttp on every routes.
        tokenGetter: (() => sessionStorage.getItem('token')),
        globalHeaders: [{'Content-Type':'application/json'}],
    }), http, options);
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: AuthHttp,
      useFactory: authHttpServiceFactory,
      deps: [Http, RequestOptions]
    }
  ]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

During the first load of the login page also if i have valid auth token there is no any `Authorization: Bearer <token>` added in the `Get` request. Sometimes it gets added in the Header and on some request there is no `Authorization` in the header.

**Image1:**

No Authorization added in the header even though there is valid token

[image: No Authorization on Header]

**Image2:**

Authorization Header Added before requesting the token to the backend.

[image: Authorization added on Header]

I am not sure about the addition of the header when does it adds and when does it removes from the header.

Have anyone else received this kind of issue?

If further details is required will add them.

Comment: Never ever show a real access token publicly!!!

Comment: @LajosArpad Yes! you are correct but this is just a test token and i would change the `JWT Private Key` and everything related to this after the authentication would work correctly.

Comment: Do not share even a test token. Replace it with something like "access_token": <my token>. Everybody will understand that there is a value you do not intend to share with us. This should be a habit, as humanely there is a danger that you accidentally share an important token due to bad habits later.

Comment: @LajosArpad Okey changed it.

Comment: I would like to help you with the effective question, but, unfortunately I am not quite an expert of Angular and/or Tymon JWT. If I were, I would have sent you an answer as well besides the comment.

Comment: Okey Np. also thank you for the reminder for the tokens. ;)